# Python 3.6 in tensorflow gpu docker images

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow

How can I have python3.6 in [tensorflow docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/).

All the images I tried (latest, nighty) are using python3.5 and I don't want to modify all my scripts.

Comment: I think you have to edit this `Dockerfile.gpu` from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile.gpu and install `python 3.6` also make it default. Don't know will it affect the tensorflow core functionality. take a try and build your custom image.

Answer (score 5):

The Tensorflow images are based on Ubuntu 16.04, as you can see from the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile). This release ships with Python 3.5 as standard.

So you'll have to re-build the image, and the Dockerfile will need editing, even though you need to do the actual build with the `parameterized_docker_build.sh` script.

[This answer on ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get) covers how to get Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

The simplest way would probably be just to change the From line in the Dockerfile to `FROM ubuntu:16.10`, and `python` to `python3.6` in the initial `apt-get install` line

Of course, this may break some other Ubuntu version-specific thing, so an alternative would be to keep Ubuntu 16.04 and install one of the alternative ppa's also listed in the linked answer:

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa &&
    apt-get update &&
    apt-get install -y python3.6
```

- Note that you'll need this after the initial `apt-get install`, because that installs `software-properties-common`, which you need to add the ppa.
- Note also, as in the comments to the linked answer, that you will need to symlink to Python 3.6.
- Finally, note that I haven't tried any of this. The may be gotchas, and you may need to make another change to ensure that the correct version of Python is used by the running container.

Comment: worked well adding the --assume-yes to `apt-install`. In my dockerfile I also added `pip3` with `RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
` what should I do with it now ?

Comment: Good point about the `yes` sorry. I've edited the answer. Not sure what you mean about what to do now? Have you built the new image as described in the README?

Answer (score 2):

You can use stable images which are supplied by third parties, like [ufoym/deepo](https://github.com/ufoym/deepo).
One that fits TensorFlow, python3.6 and cuda10 can be found [here](https://github.com/ufoym/deepo/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile.tensorflow-py36-cu100) or you can pull it directly using the command `docker pull ufoym/deepo:py36-cu100`

I use their images all the time, never had problems

Comment: +1 This is a good ressource, but is there a way to use Python3.6 in combination with tensorflow-gpu 1.xx ? ufoym/deepo seems to use the CPU version when trying to build a Docker image using their build tool, e.g. the image built from  `python generate.py Dockerfile tensorflow==1.13.1 python==3.6` does not detect any GPUs.

Comment: they have separate images for CPU and GPU, the ones specifying CUDA versions are GPU, skip the `generate.py`, look at the actual images - choose one that is a good base for you and if you need to tweak a specific version edit the Dockerfile to your liking, like change TF version or Python version

Answer (score 2):

With this anwer, I just wanted to specify how I solved this problem (the previous answer of SiHa helped me a lot but I had to add a few steps so that it worked completly).

**Context:**

I'm using a package (segmentation model for `unet++`) that requires `tensorflow==1.4.0` and `keras==2.2.2`.
I tried to use the docker image for `tensorflow 1.4.0`, however, the default version of python of this image is `3.5` which is not compatible with my package.

I managed to install `python3.6` on the docker images thanks to the following files:

My Dockerfile contains the following lines:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.4.0-gpu-py3

RUN mkdir /AI_PLATFORM
WORKDIR /AI_PLATFORM

COPY ./install.sh ./install.sh
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
COPY ./computer_vision ./computer_vision
COPY ./config.ini ./config.ini

RUN bash install.sh
```

**Install.sh:**

```
#!/urs/bin/env bash

pip install --upgrade pip
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python3-pip
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa &&
apt-get update &&
apt-get install python3.6 --assume-yes
apt-get install libpython3.6
python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Three things are important:

- use `python3.6 -m pip` instead of `pip`, else the packages are installed on `python 3.5` default version of `Ubuntu 16.04`
- use `docker run python3.6 <command>` to run your containers with `python==3.6`
- in the requirements.txt file, I had to specify the following things:

```
h5py==2.10.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1
keras==2.2.2
keras-applications==1.0.4
keras-preprocessing==1.0.2
```

I hope that this answer will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the image I created will help you. It is based on the cuda-10.0-devel image  and has tensorflow 2.0a-gpu installed.

You can use it as base image for your own implementation. The image itself doesn't do anything. I put the image on dockerhub https://cloud.docker.com/repository/docker/patientzero/tensorflow2.0a-gpu-py3.6

The github repo is located here: https://github.com/patientzero/tensorflow2.0-python3.6-Docker

Pulling it won't do much, but for completeness:

`$ docker pull patientzero/tensorflow2.0-gpu-py3.6`

edit: changed to general tensorflow 2.0x image.
Also as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22292), the official image for the beta 2.0 release now comes with python 3.6 support